# KineticJS apply multiple filters to the image and I saw a hue-filter also

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Since filters are poorly documented in the kineticJS I have a problem applying two filters to a image. Couple of questions:

1) 
I want to set  Blur and Brighten filters to the same image.

Both works separetely:

```
if (!!image.getAttr('filterBrightness')) {
   image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Brighten);
}
image.setFilterBrightness(120);
```

and

```
if (!!image.getAttr('filterAmount')){
   image.setFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Blur);
}
image.setFilterRadius(2);
```

I tried

```
image.applyFilter(Kinetic.Filters.Blur)
image.setFilterAmount(2);
```

and it worked but again when reapplyin another filter, the blur filter went off.

2) How do I correctly check if there is a filter set? I tried `getFilter()` function but firebug's console.log only shows "function".

3) There is some ShiftHue-filter, but obviously I don't understand a word from the source. See: http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Filters.html and the source (http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.js) says as below. What I don't understand is "set hue shift amount @name `setFilterBrightness`" is it a mistake in the source documentation?

How to use that filter? Set filter

```
  /**
     * get hue shift amount.  The shift amount is a number between 0 and 360.
     * @name getFilterBrightness
     * @method
     * @memberof Kinetic.Image.prototype
     */

    /**
     * set hue shift amount
     * @name setFilterBrightness
     * @method
     * @memberof Kinetic.Image.prototype
     */
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**1. At this point, I believe you can only apply 1 filter at once.**

But you can use `myImage.setFilter` to change to a different kind of filter

I just took a look at Kinetic's source code for images:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/shapes/Image.js

Line 114 defines an image's applyFilter method.

That method *doesn't iterate through a series of filters*, just one filter.call.

*So no multiple filters for now.*

I also see in the issues section there is a request for multiple filters that's categorized as an "enhancement" (meaning not yet available).

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/548

For now, if you want multiple filters you'll have to add an image manipulation plugin to your project.

**2. Checking if a filter is already set**

Internally, `image.clearFilter` works like this:

```
    clearFilter: function() {
        this.filterCanvas = null;
        this._applyFilter = false;
    }
```

So you should be able to check if filterCanvas is null or _applyFilter==false;

**3. Changing Hue**

There is a `pixelShiftHue` method in colorPack.js that:

- Converts a pixel color to HSL,
- Shifts the hue by a specified degree
- Coverts the color back to RGB
- Returns the R,G,B values of the converted color

That method is used in the brighten filter, but it's not implemented as its own filter.

Of course, you could use the code to do hue shifting yourself.

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/355c80088f396e21f412eb743620f3c70ff39023/src/filters/ColorPack.js

Answer (score 2):

markE's answer is correct in saying that there is no out of the box way to add multiple filters to an image yet.

But there is a workaround:

1. Create a Kinetic Image
2. Add a single filter to it
3. Use `toDataURL()` on the first Kinetic image, to grab the image data
4. Create a second Kinetic Image with the `dataURL` from step 3
5. Add a new filter to the image created in step 4

Here's an example based off of the 2 html5canvastutorials:

Filter Tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-invert-image-tutorial/

and

`toDataURL()` tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 300
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  //Step 1
  darth = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    image: imageObj,
    draggable: true,
    filter: Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale, //Step 2
    filterRadius: 20
  });

  layer.add(darth);
  stage.add(layer); 

  //Step 3
  var filteredDarthURL = darth.toDataURL();

  var imageObj2 = new Image();
  imageObj2.onload = function() {
    //Step 4
    var doubleFilteredDarth = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      image: imageObj2,
      draggable: true,
      filter: Kinetic.Filters.Blur, //Step 5
      filterRadius: 20
    });
    darth.destroy(); //or darth.remove() or darth.hide()
    layer.add(doubleFilteredDarth);
    layer.draw();
  }
  imageObj2.src = filteredDarthURL;


};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

Unfortunately I can't post a JSFiddle because of the Security error for trying to use `toDataURL()` on JSfiddle. But you can test it on your localhost and try it out for yourself. Works okay as an alternative, without having to use another external library to process your images.

Comment: +1 Neat answer.  I haven't tried you solution yet, how would you rate the resulting appearance?

Comment: Thanks. You can copy & paste the code above as is, into one of the HTML5CanvastTutorial links I linked above (replacing all the code inside `<script defer="defer"></script>`) to test it out easily and to rate it for on your own terms. But for me, I would say blur + grayscale looks perfect and I just tried blur + brighten which works pretty well too. Overall it looks like they stack quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll try this before multiple filters are possible. Best would be that, when using stage.toJSON the filters are put into the json-data with filter values.

Answer (score 1):

KineticJS >= 5.0

```
imgs.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale, Kinetic.Filters.Brighten, Kinetic.Filters.Sepia]);
imgs.brightness(-0.1);
imgs.noise(0.8);
```